# How to Scroll to specific number in numbered list in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, numbered-list

I like to scroll to 8.4 heading of a very lengthy document to check the content. I need to check multiple MS Word Files, so can we do by VBA or GoTo

Answer (score 0):

Go to VIEW on the menu bar and then in the SHOW group of options enable the NAVIGATION PANE and you will be able to see all the section you currently have.  You can then jump to the section you want.

Comment: Can we do this using VBA?